# Counter Example to the Following Solution?

Tags: sql

> The total score of a hacker is the sum of their maximum scores for all
> of the challenges. Write a query to print the hacker_id, name, and
> total score of the hackers ordered by the descending score. If more
> than one hacker achieved the same total score, then sort the result by
> ascending hacker_id. Exclude all hackers with a total score of 0 from
> your result.
>
> The following tables contain contest data:
>
> Hackers: The hacker_id is the id of the hacker, and name is the name
> of the hacker.
>
> Submissions: The submission_id is the id of the submission, hacker_id
> is the id of the hacker who made the submission, challenge_id is the
> id of the challenge for which the submission belongs to, and score is
> the score of the submission.

My solution below passed the test cases, but what are edge cases / input which would not pass using my solution?

```
Select ID, Name, sum(maxscore) as tot
From
    (Select ID, Name, chal, Max(score) as maxscore
    From
        (Select Submissions.hacker_id as ID,
            Hackers.name as Name,
            Submissions.score as score,
            Submissions.challenge_id as chal
        From Submissions
        Inner Join Hackers
        On Submissions.hacker_id = Hackers.hacker_id
        Where Submissions.score <> 0)
    Group by chal, ID, Name)
Group by ID, Name
Order by tot desc, ID asc;
```

Comment: your question is not clear  .. had a proper data sample  .. and the expcted .. result

Comment: You are assuming that the scores a non-negative.  That is probably reasonable, but not explicitly stated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, the quality of your question will reflect on how it is answered, please refer to [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) A good question will clearly show the issue  that you are having and include error messages or problems. Also include code that you have used and any attempts to try to resolve the issue including where you think it is failing. The more information we have the more likely we will be able to help. Please keep you question concise and only one question at a time.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select a.hacker_id,a.name,x.sum_max
from Hackers a
inner join 
    (SELECT hacker_id,sum(max_score) as sum_max
    from (
        Select hacker_id,challenge_id,max(Score) as max_score
        from submissions
        group by hacker_id,challenge_id
        ) b 
    group by hacker_id
    having sum_max>0) x
on a.hacker_id=x.hacker_id
order by sum_max desc,hacker_id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select T.hacker_id, T.name , sum(T.max_score) sum_score from (
    Select h.hacker_id, name , challenge_id, max(score) max_score
    from Hackers h 
    inner join submissions s on h.hacker_id = s.hacker_id
    group by h.hacker_id, name , challenge_id
    ) as T
group by T.hacker_id, T.name
having sum(T.max_score) > 0
order by sum_score desc , T.hacker_id
```

Answer (score -1):

This code for MySQL successfully ran the test cases.

```
select m.id, h.name, m.total from 
    (select x.hacker_id id, sum(x.max_score) total from
        (select h.hacker_id, s.challenge_id, max(s.score) as max_score from submissions as s 
        join hackers as h on h.hacker_id = s.hacker_id
        group by h.hacker_id, s.challenge_id) as x
    group by x.hacker_id
    having total <> 0)as m, 
hackers as h
where m.id = h.hacker_id
order by m.total desc, m.id;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQBu4.png)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score -1):

```
select h.hacker_id,h.name,sum(s.score) as scores from Hackers h 
inner join 
    (select hacker_id,max(score) as score
    from Submissions
    group by hacker_id,challenge_id) s 
on h.hacker_id=s.hacker_id 
group by h.hacker_id,h.name
having scores>0 
order by scores desc,h.hacker_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT A, B, sum(C)
FROM
    (SELECT h.hacker_id AS A, h.name AS B, max(s.score) AS C
    FROM Hackers h
    JOIN Submissions s
    ON s.hacker_id=h.hacker_id
    GROUP BY h.hacker_id, h.name, s.challenge_id) Sub
GROUP BY A, B
HAVING sum(C)>0
ORDER BY sum(C) DESC, A ASC;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH NOW AS (
    SELECT CHALLENGE_ID AS CI, HACKER_ID AS HI, MAX(SCORE) AS TSCORE FROM SUBMISSIONS
    WHERE HACKER_ID = HACKER_ID GROUP BY CHALLENGE_ID, HACKER_ID 
    )
SELECT C.HI, H.NAME, SUM(C.TSCORE) AS [TOTAL]  FROM NOW AS C, HACKERS AS H 
WHERE C.HI = H.HACKER_ID AND C.TSCORE > 0
GROUP BY C.HI, H.NAME ORDER BY TOTAL DESC, C.HI
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome. When answering an old question please explain in your answer how your answer is an improvement on the existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
res.hacker_id as id, 
res.name as name,
SUM(res.max_score) as score
from (
  SELECT s.challenge_id as challenge_id, h.hacker_id as hacker_id ,h.name as name,Max(score) as max_score
    FROM Hackers as h JOIN Submissions as s
    ON h.hacker_id = s.hacker_id
    GROUP BY challenge_id ,hacker_id,name 
    having max_score <> 0
) as res
GROUP BY hacker_id,name order by score desc,id asc;
```

Comment: What does this answer add to this old question more than all other answers?

Answer (score -1):

Oracle:

```
with temp as (
    select tp.hacker_id, h.name, sum(tp.score) s
    from (
        select hacker_id, submission_id, challenge_id, score,
            rank() over (partition by hacker_id, challenge_id order by score desc,
            submission_id
        ) as rank
        from submissions) tp
    join hackers h
    on h.hacker_id=tp.hacker_id
    where tp.rank=1 
    group by tp.hacker_id, h.name
    order by s desc, tp.hacker_id)
select hacker_id, name, s
from temp
where s <> 0
order by s desc, hacker_id ;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I modified [Ayman's code
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/68687631/3404097) for MS SQL:

```sql
SELECT TB1.HACKER_ID, TB1.NAME, SUM(TB2.MSCORE) 
FROM HACKERS TB1 
JOIN (SELECT hacker_id, challenge_id, MAX(Score) as MSCORE
    FROM Submissions 
    GROUP BY hacker_id, challenge_id
    ) TB2 /* submissions */
ON TB1.HACKER_ID = TB2.HACKER_ID 
GROUP BY TB1.HACKER_ID, TB1.NAME
HAVING SUM(TB2.MSCORE) > 0 
ORDER BY SUM(TB2.MSCORE) DESC, TB1.HACKER_ID ASC
```

First fetch the maximum score and group by hacker_id and challenge_id. Then in the first line the maximum score is summed, grouped by Id and named with a join.

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH cte_tbl (Hack_id, name, score, challenge_id) AS (
    SELECT
        Hackers.hacker_id, 
        Hackers.name, 
        MAX(Submissions.score), 
        Submissions.challenge_id
    FROM Hackers
    INNER JOIN Submissions
    ON Hackers.hacker_id = Submissions.hacker_id
    WHERE Submissions.score > 0 
    GROUP BY Hackers.hacker_id, Hackers.name, Submissions.challenge_id
    )
SELECT Hack_id, name, SUM(score)
FROM cte_tbl
GROUP BY Hack_id, name
ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC, Hack_id ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

Oracle:

```
select hacker_id, name, SUM(max_score) AS total_score 
FROM (
    select hacker_id, name, challenge_id, MAX(score) AS max_score 
    from hackers 
    inner join submissions using (hacker_id) 
    group by name, hacker_id, challenge_id
    ) 
WHERE hacker_id NOT IN (
    select hacker_id 
    from (
        select hacker_id, SUM(x) 
        from (
            select challenge_id, hacker_id, MAX(score) AS x 
            from submissions 
            group by challenge_id, hacker_id
            ) 
        group by hacker_id 
        having SUM(x) = 0
        ) 
    group by hacker_id
    ) 
group by hacker_id, name 
order by total_score DESC, hacker_id;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH row_numbers AS 
    (SELECT Hackers.hacker_id, name, score, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Hackers.hacker_id, challenge_id ORDER BY score DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM Hackers INNER JOIN Submissions ON Hackers.hacker_id = Submissions.hacker_id)
SELECT hacker_id, name, SUM(score) AS total_score
FROM row_numbers
WHERE RowNumber = 1
GROUP BY hacker_id, name
HAVING SUM(score) > 0
ORDER BY total_score DESC, hacker_id ASC
```

Comment: This dosn't answer the question & adds nothing to the code in the many previous answers (that don't answer the question). [answer] [Help] [meta] [meta.se] PS Code-only answers are poor, explain why/how code answers a question.

Answer (score -2):

```
select H.Hacker_id, h.Name, sum(x.Score) 
from hackers h 
inner join (   
    select hacker_id, challenge_id, max(Score) as Score 
    from Submissions 
    group by hacker_id, challenge_id
    ) x 
on H.Hacker_id = x.hacker_Id
group by H.Hacker_Id, h.Name
having sum(x.score) > 0
order by 3 desc, h.hacker_id
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome. When answering an old question please explain in your answer how your answer is an improvement on the existing answers. This also does not answer the question, which is asking for edge cases, not code.